# Why Are These Inputs Treated Differently In Python? __init__ Variables Versus Arguments.

Tags: python, python-2.7

My question pertains to the NotTrigger class in the code below. The evaluate method takes both trigger and story as inputs and both are objects that are defined earlier. Why would the evaluate method treat them differently, i.e. why is the 'trigger' variable initialized in NotTrigger's init method whereas the 'story' variable is taken as an argument to the evaluate method? Why can't both the 'trigger' and 'story' inputs be taken as arguments to the evaluate method? fyi, this is a question from MIT's online python course and when i try to treat them the same, i receive an error.

```
class Story(object): 
    def __init__(self, subject): 
        self.subject = subject 

    def getSubject(self): 
        return self.subject

class Trigger(object): 
    def evaluate(self, text): 
        return self.isWordIn(text.getSubject())

class NotTrigger(object): 
    def __init__(self, other): 
        self.trigger = trigger 

    def evaluate(self, story): 
        return not self.other.evaluate(story)
```

Comment: I would say it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: what's unclear about it. perhaps, i can improve the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is: why is the constructor - `__init__` being used here to set up state when we could just pass all arguments to the method we are going to use?

In object-oriented programming, you setup the state that a class will hold on to and use throughout it's lifetime when it is created. To intercede on that you can implement setters, but the idea is to encapsulate your state within the instance of an object, and call methods that can access that state with arguments from the outside world.

So in this case, `self.trigger` is set when the object is initialized because that object is something that NotTrigger depends on, for whatever reason. This is known as dependency injection - the notion that you should always try to be explicit about what a classes dependencies are when it is initialized because this is easier to understand and reason about than when they are injected at any time through arbitrary method calls.

So if I understand your question: why are we setting state in the class rather than just passing in what we need when we make a call? Because otherwise we would have no need of a class construct, and the state it holds on to.

Comment: thanks so much for the answer. i understand why we generally use the __init__ to inject object dependencies. my question is more around why  in the code above trigger is passed in as a dependency whereas story is passed in as an argument. why are we treating the two differently? why isn't story passed in as a dependency as well? so the question is more about why the code above treats the two differently.